# db2 between timestamp query

Tags: sql, db2

i am new to DB2 can you please help how to execute query in db2 for between timestamp with AM and PM format.

Below is the table

```
ID   NAME       TIMESTAMP
==   ====       =========
6    Xavier    02/02/2016 2:24:32 AM
7    Paul      02/02/2016 2:46:53 PM
8    Adam      02/02/2016 4:05:39 PM
9    Newton    12/02/2016 5:29:46 PM
10   Jack      14/02/2016 9:29:46 PM
```

I want to use the above table to select names on 02/02/2016 between 1AM to 4PM

Can you please help to achieve.

Comment: What is the datatype of timestamp column?

Comment: is timestamp column a string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the datatype for timestamp is `date` , use

```
select * From your_table where timestamp between
to_date('02/02/2016 01:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and 
to_date('02/02/2016 16:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

You might be seeing 'AM' / 'PM' due to your client settings.

Comment: @Hogan - Ddn't you read the the first line in the answer?? `Assuming the datatype for timestamp is date ` .Why are you giving the same information again??

Comment: Because everything about my experience for 7 years on stack overflow made me believe the asker was storing timestamp information as a string.  In fact, even though your answer was marked correct I still believe that to be the case.

Comment: Let's assume it is true. But why repeat the condition which I already mentioned in the answer? And it is not that I can't handle a downvote. You have ever right to do so but doing it based on a scenario which I already highlighted, is unnecessary IMO. Cheers and have a nice day.

Comment: At the time I wrote this comment the OP had not responded to the questions in the comments or marked your question correct -- This is a different situation now two days later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare timestamps then you need to change stuff to timestamp type.  Right now your data is strings -- I don't believe strings will work if you don't convert them.  For example 09 pm would come before 11am

```
select * 
from your_table 
where timestamp(timestamp) between timestamp('02/02/2016 01:00:00')
                               and timestamp('02/02/2016 16:00:00')
```